# Regex to get groups

Tags: javascript, regex

**I have a code that I can get the url of a span, it works and I get it normally.**

HTML

```
<span>sent</span><span><img src="myimg"></span><span class="qtd">4</span>
```

JS

```
const regexImgSrc = /<img.*?src=['"](.*?)['"]/;
img = regexImgSrc.exec(txt)[1];
```

**But I need to get the content of the QTD span, the html value 4.
How would I do that? I'm not getting.**

Comment: RegEx isn't really the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to parse HTML with regex. Use instead the following:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("span.qtd");
console.log(el.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span>sent</span><span><img src="myimg"></span><span class="qtd">4</span>
```